# Android Glide - Check if a bitmap identified by a URL is cached

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-glide

I am using Glide to display an image from internet in a notification, not in an image view. In order to do this I extended SimpleTarget like this :

```
  Glide
            .with(context.getApplicationContext())
            .load(imageUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap largeIcon, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    createNotif(largeIcon);
                    nmc.notify(notificationId, notification);
                }
            });
```

It works fine.

In order to speed up things, I would like to check the Glide cache on a specific  Image URL first and do the asynchronous query only if the bitmap is not in the cache. Something like this  (glideCache and getOnlyIfinCache is what I am looking for) :

```
    bitmap=null;
    bitmap = glideCache.getOnlyIfinCache(ImageURL);
    if (bitmap!=null) {   // the bitmap is available
        createNotif(bitmap);
        nmc.notify(notificationId, notification);
    } else {              // the bitmap is not available. Need to get it on internet
        Glide
                .with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap largeIcon, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                        createNotif(largeIcon);
                        nmc.notify(notificationId, notification);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: did u find the way??